# PHP Cross Domain Files On The Same Server

Tags: php

Before I upgraded my PHP, I used to be able to access all my files from cross domains.  I have a file structure like so:

/home
/home/domain1/public_html/index.php
/home/domain1/public_html/include-me.php

/home/domain2/public_html/index.php
/home/domain3/public_html/index.php

This is just a crude example.  But the `index.php` files in domain2 and domain3 used to be able to read the file `/home/domain1/public_html/include-me.php`, but they can't now - I just get:

`failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Is there a setting in PHP.ini that i'm missing - so I can access cross domain files again?

Comment: This appears to be simple ownership problem that occurred after you upgraded your web server. I assume you're on Linux flavor of some sort, so check what `ls -lah` says about the ownership and alter as required. You can't dabble with php.ini to fix ownership / permission problems.

Answer (score 0):

there is no crossdomain in action, it seems a problem with permission in filesystem.
are all files available for www user?

Comment: Well I thought it was to do with PHP as It only kicked into effect when I upgraded Apache.

Comment: yes this is on the php side, cross domain problems take places when the error happens in the client [the browser], but this is a server problem. Probably something went wrong in the Apache upgrade process. did it changed the www user?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with your doc root settings, Or can be a issue with file permissions on your server.

What was your version and whats the  upgraded version?

Comment: I don't know whay my previous version was, but I'm currently running 5.4.45